# Jest 22 Missing required @injectable annotation

Tags: annotations, jestjs, inversifyjs

We use [inversify](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) to register and consume certain services.

Only when I upgrade from Jest 20 to 22, I suddenly get this error in some tests:

> Missing required @injectable annotation in: MyService.

Below there is a line of code pointed to, that doesn't have anything to do with that error.

I already checked the release notes to figure out what changed, but didn't.

What could be the issue here? Why doesn't the error occur when executing the app, but only in tests with Jest 22? How can I investigate?

Comment: Jest 24 still has the same issue, btw.

Comment: It seems to be related to linked npm packages.

Answer (score 2):

this is working on my current project:

```
decorate(injectable(), ClassName);
jest.mock('../../../api/shared/ClassName');
```

Import from inversify package the decorate method to manually decorate your class right before you use jest.mock().